The Mystery deepens: What is the significance of 'el' vs. 'al' in Job Chap 1 contrasted with Chap 2?
The translation of 'My servant Job' in Job 1:8 as compared to 2:3 is identical yet the Hebrew Masoretic text there is a notable difference - 1:8 uses the preposition 'el' while 2:3 uses 'al' as was pointed out in the Question "Why the difference between "My servant Job" in 1:8 & "My servant Job" in 2:3?"  The table below shows that this difference is also in 1:11 & 2:5.
Does the symmetrical difference between 1:11 & 2:5 shed any light on the significance of the difference between 1:8 & 2:3?   Certainly, the obvious duplication of the contrast seems to rule out a casual scribal idiosyncrasy.


I have edited to link the previous question which is related but definitely not a duplicate. Please feel free to roll back if you wish. Up-voted +1.
